# Javascript getter method

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript getter method like so:

```
function passTags()
{
var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;


    this.getTag=function()
    {
        return this.tags;
    }
}
```

How do i call it?

Comment: I'd say `getTag()`, see http://javascriptgarden.info/#function.this.

Comment: @Jakub, getTag is not defined for anyone outside the passTags() function so it won't be recognised. i need to use dot notation i suppose but not sure about exact syntax required

Comment: Well if you call `passTags()` then `getTag()` should be defined in global scope.

Comment: @Jukub, surely you will agree that the point is to call passTags and to access its tag variable via the getter so i need to do it in one go...not in sequence as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've set up a constructor function, so it would be like so

```
var t = new passTags;
t.getTag();
```

`this.tags` is not defined though, so `t.getTag()` will return `undefined`. If you meant for it to return the value of `tags` then change it to

```
function passTags() {
    var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
    this.getTag = function() {
        return tags;
    }
}
```

bear in mind though that the value captured will not update once the constructor function has executed, as this **[example will demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/WZkyS/)**. One more recommendation would be to use Pascal case for the function name so that it is clear that it is a constructor function.

The way that you have your code set up at the moment though, if it wasn't intended to be a constructor function then you would first have to execute `passTags` function. This would define a function in global scope, `getTag`, that could then be executed. This will return `undefined` however as `this.tags` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Russ, that's great help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define `tags` as `var tags = ...` but as `this.tags = ...`

-- edit

Russ's solution is 'better': `tags` is now private.